# In a list of dicts, return complete dict containing highest value in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to return the dictionary with the highest value from a list of dictionaries. So because 'key1' here contains 5, I just want to get that dictionary back because it's the only one I care about. I need the value from a different key, but in the dictionary with the highest value. Should be easy but I'm missing something. Thank you!

Ex:

```
[{'key1': 1, 'key2': 'string'},
 {'key1': 3, 'key2': 'string'},
 {'key1': 5, 'key2': 'string with highest value'},
]
```

What I need to get is the dictionary '{'key1': 5, 'key2': 'string with highest value'}'

Comment: `max(ld, key=lambda d:d['key1'])['key2']` where `ld` is your list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
max(L, key=operator.itemgetter('key1'))
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Is it equal to, or faster than Steven's suggestion?

Comment: @jennifer06262016: It will be faster because `itemgetter` is implemented in C whereas the lambda function is just in Python.  In practice I wouldn't worry about it. Use the one that reads clearest to you and if your application runs slowly profile it and optimize the slow spots.

Comment: Perhaps it's obvious, but maybe include `import operator` in the answer.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification and yes I imported operator. Both answers made sense. I just started writing an awful for loop and realized it should be much less code. I was surprised SO didn't have this question. Is a list of dictionaries not common? Any general suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can write a for loop to check each item in the list:

```
data = [
    {'key1': 1, 'key2': 'string'},
    {'key1': 3, 'key2': 'string'},
    {'key1': 5, 'key2': 'string with highest value'},
]
highest = None
result = None
for item in data:
    value_key1 = item['key1']
    if highest is None or value_key1 > highest:
        highest = value_key1
        result = item['key2']

print(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

you should order the list ,then get the first
for example:

```
f = [{'key1': 1, 'key2': 'string'},
     {'key1': 3, 'key2': 'string'},
     {'key1': 5, 'key2': 'string with highest value'},
]
order_list = sorted(f,key=lambda x:x["key1"],reverse=True)
first = order_list[0]
```